# Use silent mode install informix1210 in redhat6.4, using echo $? returns 1 instead of 0

Tags: informix

Using silent install mode to install informix1210, this is the console output

```
[root@ifeTest Informix]# ./ids_install -i silent -f /installMedia/Informix/bundle.properties
[root@ifeTest Informix]# echo $?
                          1
```

But when I using gui installation, I get 0 after use echo $?

I am able to start and stop informix server using "oninit -ivy" and "onmode -kvy", also I checked the bundle_install.stderr and bundle_install.stdout, iad_act.log, , nothing show install fail in other two log files.

content in stderr

```
sun.arch.data.model=64
java.io.FileNotFoundException:     /opt/IBM/informix/uninstall/uninstall_OpenAdmin/installvariables.properties (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:156)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:69)
at com.ibm.oat.install.DetectUpgrade.install(DetectUpgrade.java:46)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.CustomAction.installSelf(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.e(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.f(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.n(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.ConsoleBasedAAMgr.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.m(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.b(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
DumpDebugInfo /tmp/028523.tmp/OAT_Debug1.log
```

I am worrying about if there any install process goes wrong for informix. Since this silent install will be official delivered in our product, just want be 100% sure about this. 
Can anyone help me on this?

Sorry, just make it more clear .

So, first time , I use -r to record the installation and get a response file,but it didn't get the server instance created,
so I manually added "IDS_SERVER_INSTANCE_BOOLEAN_1=1" in response file.
Either way I get a exit status 1

The generated response file looks like this

```
LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE
USER_INSTALL_DIR=@installLocation@
IAD_PASSWORD=@IAD_PASSWORD@
UNIX_INSTALLTYPE_SELECT=DEFAULT
LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE
USER_INSTALL_DIR=@installLocation@
IDS_INSTALL_TYPE=TYPICAL
IAD_PASSWORD=@IAD_PASSWORD@
```

So I went to edit the bundle.properties directly, still get the exit status 1.
Now, my reponse file looks like this,

```
UNIX_INSTALLTYPE_SELECT=DEFAULT; 
LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE; 
USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/IBM/informix; 
IDS_INSTALL_TYPE=TYPICAL; 
DIR_SEC_SEL_BOOLEAN_1=1; 
IAD_PASSWORD=passw0rd; 
IDS_INSTANCE_CREATE=1;
```

Comment: I suggest discussing this with IBM Technical Support.  Superficially, from the first long line in the error message, you are missing a file: `/opt/IBM/informix/uninstall/uninstall_OpenAdmin/installvariables.properties (No such file or directory)`.  I'm not sure why that would be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Informix Server 12.10.FC5** on a **CentOS 7.1**:

```
[root@tardis ~]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
[root@tardis ~]# uname -a
Linux tardis 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 13 10:06:09 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@tardis ~]# head -8 SERVER/doc/ids_machine_notes_12.10.txt

                      =================================
                            MACHINE SPECIFIC NOTES
                                    FOR
               IBM Informix Database Server 12.10.FC5 PRODUCT RELEASE
                               On Linux x86_64
                               DATE: 09 Mar 2015
                      =================================
[root@tardis ~]#
```

The reponse file you give is giving me some errors:

```
[root@tardis ~]# cat /root/setup.ini
UNIX_INSTALLTYPE_SELECT=DEFAULT;
LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE;
USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/IBM/informix;
IDS_INSTALL_TYPE=TYPICAL;
DIR_SEC_SEL_BOOLEAN_1=1;
IAD_PASSWORD=passw0rd;
IDS_INSTANCE_CREATE=1;
[root@tardis ~]# ./ids_install -f /root/setup.ini -i silent

You must indicate acceptance of the license terms prior to installation by passing -DLICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE for the silent installation mode.
[root@tardis ~]#
```

Deleting the semicolons:

```
[root@tardis ~]# cat /root/setup.ini
UNIX_INSTALLTYPE_SELECT=DEFAULT
LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE
USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/IBM/informix
IDS_INSTALL_TYPE=TYPICAL
DIR_SEC_SEL_BOOLEAN_1=1
IAD_PASSWORD=passw0rd
IDS_INSTANCE_CREATE=1
[root@tardis ~]# ./ids_install -f /root/setup.ini -i silent
[root@tardis ~]# echo $?
1
[root@tardis ~]#
```

At the logs:

```
[root@tardis ~]# egrep "Warnings|FatalErrors" /opt/IBM/informix/IBM_Informix_Software_Bundle_Install_*.log
0 Warnings
1 NonFatalErrors
0 FatalErrors
[root@tardis ~]# grep " ERROR " /opt/IBM/informix/OpenAdmin_Install_*.log
                          Additional Notes: ERROR -     class com.ibm.oat.install.CheckInstallStatus.install() runtime exception:
[root@tardis ~]#
```

This is not a **Fatal Error**, and **OAT** is up and can be used.

You've said the error is the same for you, I can't find what cause this error, but it can be related to the fact that by doing a silent installation of the **OAT** you're not giving a password for the **OAT Administrator**.

The main problem is that in silent mode this can not be done, at least to my knowledge, and you should secure it after install by creating a new administrator user and password:

```
[root@tardis ~]# /opt/IBM/informix/OAT/Apache_2.4.2/bin/htpasswd -cb /opt/IBM/informix/OAT/Apache_2.4.2/conf//.htpasswd admin passw0rd
Adding password for user admin
```

And then create the next file:

```
[root@tardis ~]# cat /opt/IBM/informix/OAT/Apache_2.4.2/htdocs/openadmin/admin/.htaccess
AuthUserFile "/opt/IBM/informix/OAT/Apache_2.4.2/conf//.htpasswd"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Folder"
Require valid-user
[root@tardis ~]#
```

Is **OAT** required? If not consider using a custom install and remove it from there. If it is required then seem to me you're stucked with these error.

In the end you should not only check the exit status but see the content of `$INFORMIXDIR/IBM_Informix_Software_Bundle_Install_*.log`, and if you find some warning the next correspondig logs:

```
IBM_Informix_GLS_Install_*.log
IBM_Informix_Client_SDK_Install_*.log
OpenAdmin_Install_*.log
IBM_Informix_12.10_Install_*.log
IBM_Informix_JDBC_Driver_Install_*.log
```

Keen regards.

Comment: Molly check the log IBM_Informix_Software_Bundle_Install_*.log on your INFORMIXDIR, by the response file you give it should be /opt/IBM/informix.

Comment: Found those content: Installation: Successful with errors.

158 Successes
0 Warnings
1 NonFatalErrors
0 FatalErrors; Install Merge Module:     $BUILD_SOURCE$/module/OpenAdmin.iam.zip
                          Status: ERROR

Comment: this is the error in OpenAdmin_install***.log  :  Custom Action:            com.ibm.oat.install.CheckInstallStatus
                          Status: ERROR
                          Additional Notes: ERROR -     class com.ibm.oat.install.CheckInstallStatus.install() runtime exception:

Comment: I've updated the answer, the problem seems to be you can't setup a password for OAT on a silent install, at least that I know. Is OAT required?

Comment: It's better that we have OAT setting tup, so you were saying that the silent install we can't set up the OAT Administrator, and it's ok that we don't have a administrator ?  As you can see the first response file , it has two IAD_PASSWORD , not sure why it has two IAD_PASSWORD generated in the response file, but it do require me to enter the informix password and admin password during gui installation. And If we want to setup the OAT Administrator, I need to run the command you suggested here, and it's all good to go?

Comment: As far as I know we can't set up the **OAT Administrator** in a silent install, I've tried a number of options to no avail.
The main problem not having an **OAT Administrator** is the fact that every body that can access **OAT Login** page can access **OAT Admin page**. Hence, I will not tell it is ok. `IAD_PASSWORD` only needs to be used if the user informix doesn't exist on the **OS** (in this case this will be the password for the user) or if you're installing on a Windows that have the user created (you must enter the existing password). It's not related to the **OAT**.